# Question on limits (0/0 form)

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

---

### Posted pic of question because i don't know how to type this question (specially roots)

Please tell me how to solve such questions..
Initially solved question ( of for 0/0,∞/∞ etc) by differentiating the numerator and denominator and then solve
But here it is getting complicated by differentiating method.

Comment: The photo is sidewise

Comment: I know, what is the problem in it.

Comment: I don't understand what is you question.  You are given a solution below the exercise. What is going there? Well $n$ gets factored out and canceled, while then by continuity of root: $\lim\sqrt{1+{a \over n}} = \sqrt{\lim\left({1 + {a \over n}}\right)} = \sqrt{1 + \lim{a\over n}}$. What is the limit of ${a\over n}$ as $n \to \infty$ given $a \in \Bbb R$ is some fixed number? ${a\over n}$ gets infinitely small and hence the root is tending to $1$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Also please use [this reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset math on this site. There are several examples of typesetting roots in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using $n\to\infty$, it is generally assumed that we're dealing with a sequence; it doesn't really matter here, because the functions $x\mapsto\sqrt{x^2+4x}$ and $x\mapsto\sqrt[3]{x^3-3x^2}$ are monotonic in a neighborhood of $\infty$.

L'Hôpital's theorem which you seem to refer to is *one of the tools*, but certainly not *the* tool of choice in every case. Indeed, if you try it, you're left with something like
$$
\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+4x}}\frac{\sqrt[3]{(x^3-3x^2)^2}}{x^2-2x}
$$
which is much worse than what you started with.

Another nice example is
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\overset{\text{(H)}}{=}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\;\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}
$$
and this loops.

In this case, collecting the largest power of $n$ is a good method; you can also do the substitution $n=1/t$ at the outset, getting
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{t^2}+\dfrac{4}{t}}}{\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{t^3}-\dfrac{3}{t^2}}}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\dfrac{\sqrt{1+4t}}{|t|}}{\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1-3t}}{t}}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+4t}}{\sqrt[3]{1-3t}}
$$
which is elementary.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'd start by suggesting that you try to follow the solution printed there. We write $\sqrt{n^2+\text{stuff}}=n\sqrt{1+\text{small stuff}}$ and $\sqrt[3]{n^3+\text{stuff}}=n\sqrt[3]{1+\text{small stuff}}$. As $n\to\infty$, the parts I've labeled "small stuff" go to zero, and the limiting ratio is $\frac{n\sqrt{1}}{n\sqrt[3]{1}}=\frac nn=1$.

When dealing with limits, the first instinct should be to focus on what's big. $n^2$ is much bigger than $4n$ as $n\to\infty$, so, looking at ratios, that numerator might as well be $\sqrt{n^2}$. Similarly, that denominator might as well be $\sqrt[3]{n^3}$. Factoring out those big terms is a good way to deal with this (with algebraic functions.

Oh, and "much bigger" has a clear technical meaning here; the ratio goes to $\infty$.